# Radon transform between affine grassmannians

Tags: reference-request, integral-transforms, integral-geometry, inverse-problems

Let $\overline{GR}(n,k)$ be the manifold of all affine k-dimensional subspaces in $R^n$, and let
$R:C^{\infty}_c(\overline{GR}(n,k))\to C^{\infty}_c(\overline{GR}(n,l))$, $0\le k<l\le n-1$, be the Radon transform defined in a standard way as follows:
$$
(Rf)(E)=\int\limits_{\{L\in \overline{GR}(n,k)):L\subset E\}}f(L)dL.
$$
Here the integration is with respect to the Haar measure on $\{L\in \overline{GR}(n,k)):L\subset E\}=\overline{GR}(k,l)$.
**QUESTION. Is the inversion formula for the Radon transform $R$ known?**

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is known.
See [Boris Rubin, *Radon transforms on affine Grassmannians*, 2004](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2004-356-12/S0002-9947-04-03508-1/), in particular theorem 4.2.
A free full text pdf is available at the linked page.
The reconstruction formula is not very simple, so I will not reproduce it here.

Radon transforms on Grassmannians are also discussed in [Helgason's book *Radon Transform*](http://www-math.mit.edu/~helgason/Radonbook.pdf), section II.4.F.